# Can't add a scrollbar to grid

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, scrollbar, scrollview

I'm writing an application on Windows Phone 7 using Silverlight.

I've spent something like 3 hours trying to add a scrollbar to grid component, so that when I add a lot of things dynamically in code, I could scroll down to see it.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Name="Scrolling">
        <ScrollViewer.Content>
          <Grid x:Name="myGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="650" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height =" 300" Background="Red" Grid.Row="1"  Margin="12,108,0,0"/>
        </ScrollViewer.Content>
    </ScrollViewer>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="79" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,405,0,0" Name="grid1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="728"> <!-- Not important -->
    </Grid>

    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Height="73" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="grid2" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="704">  <!-- Not important -->
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And then in code:

```
myGrid.Children.Add(some_component);
```

I've tried many, many ways, but none is working.
Can anyone help?

Comment: Where is the datagrid you are talking about? I only see a grid...

Comment: Also the ContentProperty of scroll viewer is Content so you don't need to specify ScrollViewer.Content...the tag is redundant

Comment: My bad, it's not a datagrid, but grid. And about ContentPropety - I've tried to solve this problem in many ways, and one of sollutions included adding this Property. Still, the problem isn't solved. How can I add a scrollbar to Grid component?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? If you can explain why you need the scrollbars (maybe draw a diagram in paint)... there are ways to do almost anything with WPF and something this simple is easily possible - what are you trying to do on the page? If you want to add dynamic rows to something you should consider using an ItemsControl - take advantage of binding etc

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to do - please post a diagram explaining what you want to do because I think that using a Grid is not what you want - if you give me an idea of what you want I can post some XAML to show you how to do it

Comment: I want it thtis way:  http://tinypic.com/r/aca9uu/6    I've found out that Windows Phone acts funny when I want to have one normal component and a scrollable one. If there's only one scrollable stackpanel, there's no problem, but if I want to add something else, it just doesn't let mi scroll anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Ok have you tried this, as your layout seems a bit strange

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid> 
        ...Static content here
    </Grid>
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
        ...Content that scales here
    </ScrollViewer>
    <Grid Grid.Row="2"> 
        ...Static content here
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

This should work fine - it helps to understand how Grid works. Also it's worth noting that most layout is possible without using margins to move things around - it's bad practice to do layout using margins because of the nature of devices and resolutions. Your apps should ALWAYS scale well - if they don't scale, people will get fed up

Grids have 3 column/row modes - auto ("auto"), absolute ("300") and fill ("*")

**Auto** - the grid cell only scales to fit the content inside it

**Absolute** - the grid cell is the size you specify

**Fill** - the grid cell fills all remaining space after any other cells with auto/absolute have been calculated, in proportion to other cells which are set to also fill

You can also speicify a relative 'fill' using "2*", "3*" etc

so:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Would result in 4 rows, the first row being 100 pixels high, the 3rd row being twice the height of the 2nd row and the 4th row being three times the height of the 2nd row. These last 3 rows would fill all remaining space.

It's also worth noting that Grid "*" fills the parent container - which is useful for filling up remaining space in applications

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't add things dynamically to a `Grid` so easily, because you'd have to update the `RowDefinitions` and `ColumnDefinitions` as well. If you don't specify those definitions, the children will be stacked in-place.

Try to use a `StackPanel` or `WrapPanel` instead, and you should see a scrollbar as soon as the children occupy enough space.

Comment: Id doesn't help. I tried both StackPanel nad WrapPanel and scrollbar doesn't appear, even if I add many items in XAML (not to mention adding them dynamicaly). And after compiling, when i attempt ro scroll the panel, the whole panel goes up, where it should only scroll it's content... :/

Comment: Also, put `Width="650"` and `Height="300"` on the `ScrollViewer` and not on its inner panel.